Gitea cannot hook to Jenkins via webhooks
the building environment as follows :
aws cloud service:
- bitnami
- gitea
szfang cloud service:

linux
jenkins

i follow this tutorial "https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_42562106/article/details/114464714" to build jenkins and gitea
currently our jenkins have:

gitea checks plugin
gitea plugin
generic event plugin
generic webhook trigger plugin

while we alreadly set an account in gitea, and give enough permission to both jenkins and gitea
but the direction of
gitea --> webhook --> Jenkins
will have failed due to context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
------------------------------ 2024/11/07---------------------
we tried the following attempts:

allow all white_list in the gitea side, that is (ALLOWED_HOST_LIST=*)
create all combination of jenkins credentials for gitea
install different plugin as previous section mentioned

